# PayPal integration on Phonegap build application android

Tags: paypal, phonegap-build

I need to integrate paypal payment gateway with my Phonegap + jquerymobile application for android platform. I need similar to native Paypal Android SDK. Please point me towards the right direction or if there is another way. I tried a few libraries but it seems like they are outdated. 
Note: I am using build.phonegap

Comment: As with anything done on Cordova/Phonegap use a plugin. http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this official [paypal plugin](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/), its preferred over other third party plugin services due to security reasons.
Its documented and its being updated and in track.

Comment: Yes I tried that before. But I am confused; which files to add and which not. Currently I created a new project and just added index.html, index.js (same as in the tutorial) and config.xml in which I am referencing <gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" source="npm" />

Comment: It does not even let me build on phonegap build. Gives me the error as "Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server."